# Javascript: adding an integer and decimal giving wrong answer

Tags: javascript

When I try to add a decimal value with an integer, I am getting a wrong answer.

Here's what I am doing: I am getting 4 numbers from a string like the following: 
8' 9'' X 7' 4'' into 4 variables: v1, v2, v3, v4

Then I am dividing the 2nd and 4th numbers v2, v4 by 12 (to convert inches to feet in decimal) and saving them into two more variables v5, v6

So,

```
v5 = v2/12; // 9/12 = 0.75
v6 = v4/12; // 4/12 = 0.33
```

Everything is working fine till here, and it is giving the correct results. Then, when I try to add v1+v5, and v2+v6, I am getting a wrong answer.

```
v7 = v1+v5 // 8+0.75 should be 8.75; but I am getting 80.75
v8 = v2+v6 // 7+0.33 should be 7.33; but I am getting 70.33
```

Answer (score 5):

You are just merging the two variable is Not performing a addition .so you need `parse` the variable using [`parseFloat()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi43t61uY_UAhUIuI8KHczKAgoQFggsMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FparseFloat&usg=AFQjCNFGjOkpZ1cWnWNYHgjw0eQjZTiL0g&sig2=o1PCQFIimzIGglYOI_ZnMg) .They convert  ***string to number***

```
v7 = parseFloat(v1)+parseFloat(v5)
v8 = parseFloat(v2)+parseFloat(v6)
```

**Working example**

```js
v1 = "8"
v2 = "7"
v5 = "0.75"
v6 = "0.33"
v7 = parseFloat(v1) + parseFloat(v5)
v8 = parseFloat(v2) + parseFloat(v6)

console.log(v7,v8)
```

Comment: *v5* and *v6* are numbers, not strings since `string÷number` gives a number. `parseInt(v1) + v5` or `+v1 + v5` is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with the type of your variable.
You could try to `parseInt()` / `parseFloat` them.

`v7 = parseFloat(v1) + parseFloat(v5)`

Comment: No, don't use eval.

Comment: @RobG removed from my answer.